# Java: simple way of displaying some SQL data in browser & interact

Tags: java, web-services

I have an SQL database running. All the java interaction with it is clear. 
Now I want to display the result of some queries (say `SELECT * FROM example`) and let the user  make queries (`DELETE FROM example`) with a couple of buttons from within the browser.

What's a not too complex way of doing that? My head is buzzing with words like JAX-WS, JSP, Servlets etc. Easiest way seems to be JSP, but I heard its deprecated and while doing this simple task I also want to learn something useful for the future :)

What would you recommend? Also, if you could point me to a good tutorial would be nice, because all the tutorials I found for Java webservices included writing a client, not using them from within the browser.

Comment: I think what he/she means "simplest" is a quick and basic way of doing it without any overheads of using struts/spring/oRMs etc. Am i right?

Comment: Thank you Kaipa, thats exactly what I meant. 

@Andrew: Very clever. Edited out some simples, I hope the question now meets your standards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways of doing what you want, i'll list a couple:

**on the server side.**

1. Use a REST framework  like [jersey](http://jersey.java.net/)
2. Use servlets.

I'd recommend REST, and [here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/REST/article.html) you can find a tutorial.

On the client side, you'll need to use javascript to send ajax requests.

I suggest you take a look at [jquery](http://jquery.com/), which is a javascript framework that would make your life much easier. [here](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/15-resources-to-get-you-started-with-jquery-from-scratch/) are some great resources for learning it.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you *trust* your users very much, the simplest thing would be to create a simple HTML page with a text box and let the user type in the queries to his/her heart's content. You can then pass whatever text the user typed in directly to the database and throw out the results.

You could use the [Spring](http://www.springsource.org/) framework for this, if you want to learn something new in the process. It might be an overkill, but considering the simplicity of the application (in your case) this exercise might be a good way to get you started.

Comment: Um.. 'thrust'->'trust'?  Unless you are going to thrust the users out an open window if they trash the DB. ;)

Comment: @AndrewThompson: Fixed. Even though most of the time you need to keep your options open ;)

Comment: I dont have any users, this is just for letting a friend know some basic stuff about whats going on in the DB while sparing him the hassle of ssh'ing into the server and doing the queries himself.

Comment: @user804967: If that is the case, your friend might also find something such as the [MySQL GUI Tools](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/gui-tools/5.0.html) helpful. You can still keep going with the Web Application, since only your friend will be using it you should be fine, just make sure to have some back ups so that you can quickly restore and keep on going should he/she drop the entire database.

Answer (score 0):

If anyones interested, i ended up using tapestry.apache.org which comes with a good starting tutorial :)

Comment: Ascorbin, if this is your accepted answer, then you should click the checkmark next to this answer.  That helps people see the question had some resolution.  Also, your answer could be more helpful to people if you edit the answer and add a link to the tutorial you mention.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try [ZK framework](http://www.zkoss.org), which is simple & easy. You can check their [awesome live demos](http://www.zkoss.org/demo/) to feel how simple & easy it is. Also, they have a online [sandbox](http://www.zkoss.org/zksandbox/) web application, you can try zk code in it.

eg, the following code will query the database and display result to user. Don't be surprise that such piece of code will run if you filled the code of database access part.

**index.zul**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<zk>
    <button label='Query database' onClick='QueryAndDisplay()'/>
    <grid id='gridQueryResult'>
        <columns/>
        <rows/>
    </grid>
    <zscript><![CDATA[
    import java.sql.*;
    void QueryAndDisplay ()
    {
        // clear displayed content
        org.zkoss.zul.Columns cols = gridQueryResult.getColumns();
        org.zkoss.zul.Rows rows = gridQueryResult.getRows ();

        // ...
        // query the database, get the result set
        //...
        ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
        for (int i=1; i<rsmd.getColumnCount(); i++)
        {
            // display the columns
            org.zkoss.zul.Column col = new org.zkoss.zul.Column (rsmd.getColumnName(i));
            cols.appendChild (col);
        }
        while (rs.next())
        {
            for (int i=1; i<rsmd.getColumnCount(); i++)
            {
                org.zkoss.zul.Row row = new org.zkoss.zul.Row (rs.getString(i));
                rows.appendChild (row);
            }
        }

        // close database
        // ...
    }
    ]]></zscript>
</zk>
```